# expected unqualified-id before token... 'std::'

Tags: c++, eclipse, android-ndk, std

When i compile C++ code in an Android NDK project i get:

```
    expected unqualified-id before '(' token    FPEnvironment_DUMMY.h   /PocoFoundation/jni/include/Poco    line 98 C/C++ Problem
```

The error origins from the lines:

```
    inline bool FPEnvironmentImpl::isInfiniteImpl(double value)
    {
        return std::isinf(value) != 0;
    }
```

The following packet is included:

```
    #include <cmath>
```

It seems that the error disappear when i remove std::, why does this happen?
I have to many source files to remove the class name std in all of them :/

Comment: What does this have to do with `std::istream`?

Comment: Create a cpp file with nothing except `void test(){std::isinf(7);}` and the `#include` required to make it compile.  That work?

Comment: Same problem:

#include <cmath> void test(){std::isinf(7);}

Changing it to the following removes the error:
#include <cmath> void test(){isinf(7);}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution i found is :

remove std:: from the header-files signalled by the errors when building according to [this](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/99300-AndroidPlatformNotes.html)

Since we next were going to include the static lib we built here in an eclipse-Android project the new compilation required std:: in the headers again so we simply reverted them back to their original style std::isinf etc. The usage of std:: depends on what stdlibrary you use, gnu or stdl_port..

The issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/57)